# Get current hour with Protractor

Tags: date, protractor, hour

I need to test an agenda and I need getting the actual date and current hour to assert with the agenda values.

This not works:

```
var d = new Date();
expect(day.getText()).toEqual(d.getDate());
```

Comment: What format are you looking for (`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm` or something else)? Can you update that in your question?

Comment: Would be useful to know the cotext - what the `day` is (I assume it's a DOM node) and what is it displaying. Also when you say it does not work - what message do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get current hour using JavaScript inbuilt [`getHours()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp) method. Here's its usage -

```
var cTime = Date().getHours();
```

or

```
var d = new Date();
var cTime = d.getHours(); //prints the current hour only
```

And you can get the actual date using [`getDate()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) method which prints a string of values related to current date and time. Sample format: `Fri Nov 20 2015 20:24:38 GMT+0530 (IST)`. Hope it helps